# how to call private fields in eosio (c++)

Tags: c++, eos

I have two versions of response in eosio :

v. **1.8.1**

```
block_state::block_state( pending_block_header_state&& cur,
                             const signed_block_ptr& b,
                             vector<transaction_metadata_ptr>&& trx_metas,
                             const std::function<void( block_timestamp_type,
                                                       const flat_set<digest_type>&,
                                                       const vector<digest_type>& )>& validator,
                             bool skip_validate_signee
                           )
   :block_header_state( std::move(cur).finish_next( *b, validator, skip_validate_signee ) )
   ,block( b )
   ,trxs( std::move(trx_metas) ) <-----
   {}
```

v. **2.0.11**

```
block_state::block_state( pending_block_header_state&& cur,
                             signed_block_ptr&& b,
                             vector<transaction_metadata_ptr>&& trx_metas,
                             const protocol_feature_set& pfs,
                             const std::function<void( block_timestamp_type,
                                                       const flat_set<digest_type>&,
                                                       const vector<digest_type>& )>& validator,
                             const signer_callback_type& signer
                           )
   :block_header_state( inject_additional_signatures( std::move(cur), *b, pfs, validator, signer ) )
   ,block( std::move(b) )
   ,_pub_keys_recovered( true ) // called by produce_block so signature recovery of trxs must have been done
   ,_cached_trxs( std::move(trx_metas) ) <-----
   {}
```

it works fine with first version :

```
for (const auto &transaction : block->trxs)
{  }
```

but when i want call similarly in second :

```
for (const auto &transaction : block->_cached_trxs)
{  }
```

I have an error :

```
_cached_trxs is a private member of 'eosio::chain::block_state'
```

How can i resolve this issue?

UPD: Added source link
[src](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/v2.0.11/libraries/chain/block_state.cpp)

Comment: Your for loop is outside the block_state class, but is trying to access a private member of the class. The error is completely expected in this case. 
I suggest you look at the public part of the class instead and see which public functions you can use for access

Comment: updated a body of question. Added a source link. I'm newbee in c++, and could you pls check  it and tell if there is some public method for this, i cannot find. And maybe I'm just not looking there :-)

Answer (score 0):

My C++ is a bit rusty, but it looks like you can access it using the extract_trx_metas method of the pending_state object.

[eos/libraries/chain/controller.cpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/26a4d285d0be1052d962149e431eb81500782991/libraries/chain/controller.cpp) line 101